# Sublime3 Proxy Settings (No plaintext password)

Tags: sublimetext3

Does anyone know if there is a way to either get Sublime3 to use a proxy without storing the password in plaintext? I cannot bring myself to store a password in plaintext.

If there is not a way to do that, is there a way to get Sublime3 to use the system's proxy settings?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess you're referring to Package Control as opposed to ST itself? what platform are you on? https://github.com/wbond/package_control/issues/441

Comment: @Keith Hall, yes u was referring to package control but would also like to be able to do FTP saving. I need it to work on Windows and Linux. I have seen the solution you posted, but it does not seem to work. Proxy info still needs to be stored in plain text.